Litigating against US government as a foreigner outside the US fully remotely-possible?
So I have a couple of q's on how district courts in the US operate in cases when a foreigner is suing a government agency in a civil proceeding. Firstly, do district courts generally allow for a fully remote proceeding via videoconferencing in cases when the plaintiff cannot attend in person simply because they cannot come to the US without a visa? Is this simply a formality to request this or do judges normally deny such requests? Secondly, there's also an issue of responding to motions from the other side. I've read that one may request electronic filing to be used for full case processing but let's say the judge denies this and the foreigner has to correspond by physical mail, does the court extend the time for responding to motions from the other side given there may be hiccups in international mailing or is it still 10-14 days as per usual?

Are we assuming that the hypothetical foreigner is proceeding pro se?  Most of these issues would normally be resolved by hiring local council.

@JustinCave Furthermore, litigating against the U.S. government without a lawyer is simply foolhardy. No sane person would do that unless they are in prison and have no other choice.


Firstly, do district courts generally allow for a fully remote
proceeding via videoconferencing in cases when the plaintiff cannot
attend in person simply because they cannot come to the US without a
visa? Is this simply a formality to request this or do judges normally
deny such requests?

U.S. District Courts routinely permit remote appearance upon a timely request for things like status conferences and scheduling conferences. They also sometimes allow a minor witness (e.g. someone authenticating a document, or providing five minutes of not hotly contested fact testimony) to testify remotely.
It would be unusual for a U.S. District Court to allow a party or a core witness to testify or participate in an evidentiary hearing (e.g. a trial on the merits) remotely. The U.S. District Court has discretion to allow that but it would not be wise to assume that it will be allowed. Filing a lawsuit in a court generally implies consent to appear in person at a trial in that court.

Secondly, there's also an issue of responding to motions from the
other side. I've read that one may request electronic filing to be
used for full case processing but let's say the judge denies this and
the foreigner has to correspond by physical mail, does the court
extend the time for responding to motions from the other side given
there may be hiccups in international mailing or is it still 10-14
days as per usual?

Lawyers admitted to practice in a U.S. District Court e-file everything and receive everything via e-filing.
It is rare for parties without lawyers to be granted permission to e-file, although it is being done on a trial basis these days. In lieu of e-filing, the norm is service by snail mail, and there is no special extension of time to respond to motions when the person served with documents under F.R.C.P. 5 (pertaining to delivery of documents during a lawsuit) is abroad, even though mail to these places can take longer.
The work around would be to check PACER where all e-filings are visible, every couple of days, without waiting to see if any documents arrive in the mail.
Getting documents filed by a party without e-filing delivered to the court and opposing parties in a timely fashion that meets the relevant deadlines could be challenging too. It might be possible to e-mail or fax the documents to the U.S. and to have someone mail or hand deliver them to the court and other parties from the U.S. without having this constitute unauthorized practice of law.
Further Observation
As a practical matter, someone who brings a lawsuit against the U.S. government from outside the U.S. without a lawyer is a fool and should never have started the lawsuit. Their chances of gaining a favorable result approach zero.
It is also worth mentioning that entities, as opposed to natural persons, cannot participate in lawsuits in U.S. District Court without having a lawyer. Their non-lawyer officers or managers or trustees or directors can't represent them in court.

Also: suing the US government outside of the things for which it agrees to be sued is not possible.

Thanks for the detailed response. Want to clarify. If I were to be represented by a US licensed attorney who lives in Europe, then will it be possible for this attorney to be allowed to litigate on my behalf at a US district court remotely? Or will he/she also be denied?

@Cognitive_impotence Each U.S. District Court has its own separate bar membership. A U.S. licensed attorney who is not admitted in that particular U.S. District Court could be admitted either pro hac vice (i.e. for that particular case) or on a permanent basis, to that U.S. District Court's bar.
